# Is it possible to request a longer Schengen visa / apply for a new one before I leave for my trip?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I recently got approved for a 15 day France-issued Schengen visa. I would also like to visit Switzerland and stay longer in France. The trip is still months away. Is it possible to request an extension, can I apply to France for a new visa, or to Switzerland? The problem is that:
I would like to stay from approximately May 21 to Jun 19 (clearly less than 90 days...) But France only issued me 15 days with validity from May 14 to Jun 14. This makes it impossible to apply for another Schengen visa valid before Jun 15. What should I do here? Apply for a Switzerland Schengen visa from May 21 to Jun 19 and stay in France for the beginning part and Switzerland as intended?

Comment: Did you _request_ a visa covering a one-month stay ending 19 June and they issued a shorter ones, or are you now changing your plans?

Comment: @Henning Makholm I want to change my plans, if possible. Do you know if it can be done?

Comment: Plans can be changed but unless you have a very strong position, you risk losing the visa you already have. (And please, do not ask again. Edit this question if you want to add information, that also brings the question to the top again.)

Comment: Is this your first Schengen visa? If so, you might be best to stick to your original plan

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.